# nautilus 3.4 wit nautilus 3.6 interface

Tags: nautilus, interface

I am not a fan of the 3.6 release, but I like how it looks.
 
Is there a way to get the nautilus 3.6 interface?

[image: nautilus 3.6]

on my nautilus 3.4?
[image: nautilus 3.4]

Comment: No, unless you recompile Nautilus 3.4 and I'd suggest you to wait for proper themes to appear. There are forks of Nautilus 3.4 that look almost like that such as the SolusOS fork.

Comment: @UriHerrera. Please post that comment as an answer then i'l accept it?

Answer (score 0):

I think the closest you can get is **SolusOS Patched Nautilus** as seen here:

[Install SolusOS Patched Nautilus In Ubuntu 12.04 ~ Web Upd8: Ubuntu / Linux blog](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/08/install-solusos-patched-nautilus-in-ubuntu-1204.html)

In brief, you can install and start using it by entering these commands in terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/experiments
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
nautilus -q
```